# WPF Usercontrol databinding with MVVM ViewModel

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, user-controls

I have spent quite some time on this so seeking help.

Simple data binding with usercontrol with mvvm light does not work.

I have done the following.

1. Created a MvvmLight (WPF451) project using VS 2015 and named it WpfDataBindingUserControlT1
2. Added a UserControl and renamed it to SimpleUserControl.xaml
3. Added some lables as a children(wraped in stackpanel) to the grid inside SimpleUserControl.xaml(All code is given below)
4. Added a dependency properties in the code behind of the SimpleUserControl.xaml(SimpleUserControl.cs) so that these will help me in databinding.

The data binding simply does not work. I have pulled half of my hair on this so please help. I guess I am missing very simple on this.

The code is as follows.

1. MainWindows.xaml

   ```
   <Window x:Class="WpfDataBindingUserControlT1.MainWindow"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
           xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
           xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
           xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
           xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfDataBindingUserControlT1"
           mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
           Height="400"
           Width="300"
           Title="MVVM Light Application"
           DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

       <Window.Resources>
           <ResourceDictionary>
               <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                   <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
               </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
           </ResourceDictionary>
       </Window.Resources>

       <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

           <TextBlock FontSize="36"
                      FontWeight="Bold"
                      Foreground="Purple"
                      Text="{Binding WelcomeTitle}"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      TextWrapping="Wrap" />

           <local:SimpleUserControl DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" CellValue="{Binding WelcomeTitle}" />
       </Grid>
   </Window>
   ```
2. MainWindow.cs ( I did not change any thing in this file.)

   ```
   using System.Windows;
   using WpfDataBindingUserControlT1.ViewModel;

   namespace WpfDataBindingUserControlT1
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
       /// </summary>
       public partial class MainWindow : Window
       {
           /// <summary>
           /// Initializes a new instance of the MainWindow class.
           /// </summary>
           public MainWindow()
           {
               InitializeComponent();
               Closing += (s, e) => ViewModelLocator.Cleanup();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. SimpleUserControl.xaml

   ```
   <UserControl x:Class="WpfDataBindingUserControlT1.SimpleUserControl"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfDataBindingUserControlT1"
                mc:Ignorable="d" 
                d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
       <Grid>
           <StackPanel>
               <Label Content="This Prints" />
               <Label Name="MyLable" Content="{Binding Path=CellValue}"></Label>
               <Label Content="This also Prints" />
           </StackPanel>
       </Grid>
   </UserControl>
   ```
4. SimpleUserControl.cs (added a dependency prop)

   ```
   using System.Windows;
   using System.Windows.Controls;

   namespace WpfDataBindingUserControlT1
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// Interaction logic for SimpleUserControl.xaml
       /// </summary>
       public partial class SimpleUserControl : UserControl
       {
           public string CellValue
           {
               get { return (string)GetValue(CellValueProperty); }
               set { SetValue(CellValueProperty, value); }
           }

           public static readonly DependencyProperty CellValueProperty = 
               DependencyProperty.Register("CellValue", typeof(string), typeof(SimpleUserControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
               {
                   BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
               });

           public SimpleUserControl()
           {
               InitializeComponent();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. MainViewModel.cs (I have not changed any thing in this)

   ```
   using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
   using WpfDataBindingUserControlT1.Model;

   namespace WpfDataBindingUserControlT1.ViewModel
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// This class contains properties that the main View can data bind to.
       /// <para>
       /// See http://www.mvvmlight.net
       /// </para>
       /// </summary>
       public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
       {
           private readonly IDataService _dataService;

           /// <summary>
           /// The <see cref="WelcomeTitle" /> property's name.
           /// </summary>
           public const string WelcomeTitlePropertyName = "WelcomeTitle";

           private string _welcomeTitle = string.Empty;

           /// <summary>
           /// Gets the WelcomeTitle property.
           /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
           /// </summary>
           public string WelcomeTitle
           {
               get
               {
                   return _welcomeTitle;
               }
               set
               {
                   Set(ref _welcomeTitle, value);
               }
           }

           /// <summary>
           /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
           /// </summary>
           public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
           {
               _dataService = dataService;
               _dataService.GetData(
                   (item, error) =>
                   {
                       if (error != null)
                       {
                           // Report error here
                           return;
                       }

                       WelcomeTitle = item.Title;
                   });
           }

           ////public override void Cleanup()
           ////{
           ////    // Clean up if needed

           ////    base.Cleanup();
           ////}
       }
   }
   ```
6. ViewModelLocator.cs (I have not changed any thing in this as well.)

   ```
   /*
     In App.xaml:
     <Application.Resources>
         <vm:ViewModelLocatorTemplate xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfDataBindingUserControlT1.ViewModel"
                                      x:Key="Locator" />
     </Application.Resources>

     In the View:
     DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=ViewModelName}"
   */

   using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
   using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc;
   using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;
   using WpfDataBindingUserControlT1.Model;

   namespace WpfDataBindingUserControlT1.ViewModel
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// This class contains static references to all the view models in the
       /// application and provides an entry point for the bindings.
       /// <para>
       /// See http://www.mvvmlight.net
       /// </para>
       /// </summary>
       public class ViewModelLocator
       {
           static ViewModelLocator()
           {
               ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

               if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
               {
                   SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, Design.DesignDataService>();
               }
               else
               {
                   SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
               }

               SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
           }

           /// <summary>
           /// Gets the Main property.
           /// </summary>
           [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance",
               "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic",
               Justification = "This non-static member is needed for data binding purposes.")]
           public MainViewModel Main
           {
               get
               {
                   return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
               }
           }

           /// <summary>
           /// Cleans up all the resources.
           /// </summary>
           public static void Cleanup()
           {
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line to your `SimpleUserControl.cs` constructor

```
public SimpleUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    (this.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;
}
```

You're basically setting the `DataContext` of the first element in the `UserControl`.

Jerry Nixon has a great article on this [here](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/07/solved-two-way-binding-inside-user.html)

**UPDATE**
forgot to add get rid of the `RelativeSource` eg

```
<local:SimpleUserControl CellValue="{Binding WelcomeTitle}" />
```

Comment: Its not working. But either way I have observed I get the following error System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'WelcomeTitle' property not found on 'object' ''SimpleUserControl' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=WelcomeTitle; DataItem='SimpleUserControl' (Name=''); target element is 'SimpleUserControl' (Name=''); target property is 'CellValue' (type 'String'). Not able to decipher whats wrong

Comment: see my update. Ive tested with your code and it works only difference being I dont use `IDataService` just hard coded string for `WelcomeTitle`